# Rails ActiveRecord delete record, associated records deleted one at a time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Here is an example... I have a users table that references preferences.  The preferences table has a user_id.  When I delete a user, I want to delete the records in the preferences table as well.  However, using the `belongs_to` and `has_many` association methods in the models, I get this activity on the database:

```
  preference Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `preferences`.* FROM `preferences` WHERE `preferences`.`user_id` = 2
  SQL (1.3ms)  DELETE FROM `preferences` WHERE `preferences`.`id` = 2
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `preferences` WHERE `preferences`.`id` = 6
  SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM `preferences` WHERE `preferences`.`id` = 16
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `preferences` WHERE `preferences`.`id` = 28
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `preferences` WHERE `preferences`.`id` = 34
  SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM `preferences` WHERE `preferences`.`id` = 44
  userAccount Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `user_accounts`.* FROM `user_accounts` WHERE `user_accounts`.`user_id` = 2
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `user_accounts` WHERE `user_accounts`.`id` = 2
```

Is there a proper way to delete the record using perhaps `DELETE FROM preferences WHERE user_id = xxxx`?  I'd like to do that way, because if the preferences had millions of rows, could be a lengthy query.

```
# User model
has_many :preferences, dependent: :destroy

# Preferences model
belongs_to :user
```

I could just overwrite the `destroy` method, but I want to see if there is a more elegant way to do this...

Comment: You need to process each Preference instance one by one in order to call the destroy callback (other dependent: :destroy defined on Preference model) on each Preference record.

Comment: Your user model has `has_many :users`? Is that typo?

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was a typo in the thread, not the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the [`dependent: :delete_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3a%3aAssociations%3a%3aClassMethods-label-Delete+or+destroy?) option, instead of `dependent: :destroy`:

```
has_many :preferences, dependent: :delete_all
```

This will execute `delete from preferences where user_id = {user_id}`.